# Why can't passport.js deserialize a user after I restart my server?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

**Problem** I am using passport.js to authenticate my users. Everything works fine, they can log in. Their id gets serialized into the session, and also get deserialized on acessesing req.user on the subsequent requests. But when I close my server down, or restart, and go to any route. It gives me an error, 'cannot deserialize user out of session'. I noticed that when I delete the user session from my database(I am using cloud hosted mongo-db), I have to login again and it works fine, until I restart my server again(which is frequent in development). I cannot delete the session, again and again and then again login. That is a huge hassle. Does anyone have any idea to what might be causing this?

**Edit**
Here are my codes Im using:

*passport.js strategy file*

```
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('./../models/user.js');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField : 'email'}, (email, password, done) => {
  //see if the user with such username exists
  User.findOne({email}, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err, false, {message : "Something went wrong."});
    }

    if(!user) {
      return done(null, false, {message : "No such user exists."});
    }

    //check if the password matches
    bcrypt.compare(password , user.password).then(match => {
      if(!match) {
        return done(null, false, {message : "Password and email doesn't match."});
      }
      done(null, user, {message : "Log in successful"});
    }).catch(err => {
      done(err, false, {message : "Something went wrong. Try again."});
    });

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
      done(null, user._id, );
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
      User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
      })
    });
  });
})
);
```

Session config:

```
app.use(session({
  secret : process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  name : "PizzaCartSession",
  resave : false,
  store : mongoStore,
  saveUninitialized : false,
  cookie : {maxAge : 1000 * 60 * 60,} // 4 hours
}));
```

Comment: Does passport.js need/use a certificate which may is autogenerated on each start?

Comment: I dont know. I'm really new to using passport. I just followed throught the documentation.

Comment: I know this wouldn't be a problem, after I deploy the app to remote server. But as of now, I need to restart the server very often.

Comment: I don't know passport.js but another auth library I used had the exact same behaviour and it originated from an autogenerated temp dev cert. So finding out if you could provide one from a file would solve your problem (especially later when deployed to the server).

Comment: What does your `session` configuration look like?

Comment: @jasonandmonte I have included it.

Answer (score 1):

If my answer is useful add vote :D 
I had a same issue like you. I spended 3-4 hours to resolve this problem. 
**I Don't know why but a lot of tutorial added serialize and deserialize into Local-Strategy - it's wrong!!!**  Serializing and deserializing belong to passport instance so we can do it before or after local-strategy. **Remember** to add all passport config(local-strategy, serializing&deserializing) after `express-session` and before `passport.initialize() & passport.session()`. 

`Error: failed to deserialize user out of session` - login works because you fire up local-strategy where you have implemented serializing and deserializing and server know what they have to do. When you checking active session from cookie in FrontEnd you didn't fire up local-strategy and server don't know what deserializing is.

Code

1. File: './server.js'

```js
// Express Session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.secret,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    // Default store is only for debug - Save session in MongoDB
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      collection: 'sessions',
    }),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // one day
    },
  })
);

// Added & Init Passport Local Config for entire App
require('./config/passportConfig')(passport);
// Init passport & session
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

2. File: './config/passportConfig'

```js
const User = require('../models/User');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// Why we pass instances of passport to functions when we call it  ??
// Bc we want the same instane of passort in our entire appliaction
module.exports = (passport) => {
//----------Start Local-Strategy----------//
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      { usernameField: 'email' }, // we show that we have an email field like username
      async (email, password, done) => {
        try {
          // 1. Looking for User & his paassword in DB by email
          const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');
          // 2. Checking if user exists
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {
              // If not exist stop function and return msg to login control
              msg: 'That email is not registered',
            });
          }
          // 3. Comparing password from form with password from DB
          // Using method from UserSchema
          const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password);
          if (isMatch) {
            // If is match stop function adn return user to login control
            return done(null, user, { msg: 'User Found' });
          } else {
            // If not exist stop function and return msg to login control
            return done(null, false, { msg: 'Incorrect Password' });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          // If error with connection with DB return msg  to login control
          console.error(error);
          return done(null, false, { msg: 'Server Error' });
        }
      }
    )
  );
//----------End of Local-Strategy----------//
  // Serialize only user id
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  // Deserialize by user id
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id)
      .then((user) => {
        done(null, user);
      })
      .catch((err) => done(err));
  });
};
```

If you want more code [check my repo](https://github.com/dudek-igor/MERN__Stateful_User_Authentication_via_Passport.js). FrontEnd - React, BackEnd - Express.